# How refactor readChunk from SFTPFile to stop using inlineCallbacks?

Tags: python, twisted, sftp

I'm trying to read from file over `ISFTPFile` and I want to avoid using `@inlinceCallbacks` in this scenario?

Or maybe there is a better way to read/write for `ISFTPFile`?

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def calculate_checksum(open_file):
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()

    offset = 0
    try:
        while True:
            d = yield open_file.readChunk(offset, chunk_size)
            offset += chunk_size
            hasher.update(d)

    except EOFError:
        pass

    target_checksum = hasher.hexdigest()
    defer.returnValue(target_checksum)


client_file = client.openFile(
    filename=target, flags=FXF_READ, attrs={})
checksum = yield client_file.addCallback(calculate_checksum)
```

Comment: Try here for refactoring or code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You effectively want to map sha256.update over an iterator of file chunks:

```
hasher = hashlib.sha256()
chunks = read_those_chunks()
map(hasher.update, chunks)
return hasher.hexdigest()
```

Note that the explicit iteration from the original `calculate_checksums` (using the while loop) is now hidden inside of `map`.  Basically, `map` has replaced the iteration.

The obstacle is that you want to avoid a `read_those_chunks` which loads the whole file into memory (presumably).  So, as a first step, implement that piece:

```
def read_those_chunks(open_file, chunk_size):
    offset = 0
    while True:
        yield open_file.readChunk(offset, chunk_size)
        offset += chunk_size
```

There's a generator that yields `Deferred`s that fire with subsequent chunks (or `EOFError`).  Unfortunately, you can't use this with `map`.  So now implement a map-alike that can deal with this:

```
def async_map(function, iterable):
    try:
        d = next(iterable)
    except StopIteration:
        return

    d.addCallback(function)
    d.addCallback(lambda ignored: async_map(function, iterable))
    return d
```

Since `async_map` is going to replace `map` and `map` replaced the iteration from the original implementation, `async_map` is still responsible for making sure we visit every chunk from the iterable.  However, iteration (with either `for` or `while`) doesn't mix well with `Deferred` (mixing them is when you typically pull out `inlineCallbacks`).  So `async_map` doesn't iterate.  It recurses - a common alternative to iteration.  Each recursive call operates on the next element of the iterable until there are no more (or until a `Deferred` fails, as will happen in this case due to `EOFError`).

Recursion works better than iteration with `Deferred` because recursion operates on functions and function calls.  `Deferred` can deal with functions and function calls - pass a function to `addCallback` and `Deferred` will eventually call that function.  Iteration is made up of small pieces of a function (sometimes called "blocks" or "suites") and `Deferred` can't deal with these.  You can't pass a block to `addCallback`.

Now use these two to create a `Deferred` that fires when the digest has been computed:

```
def calculate_checksum(open_file, chunk_size):
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    chunks = read_those_chunks(open_file, chunk_size)
    d = async_map(hasher.update, chunks)
    d.addErrback(lambda err: err.trap(EOFError))
    d.addCallback(lambda ignored: hasher.hexdigest())
    return d
```

You may also  notice that `async_map` differs from `map` in that it doesn't produce a list of results of the function calls it makes.  Perhaps it's more like `reduce`:

```
def async_reduce(function, iterable, lhs):
    try:
        d = next(iterable)
    except StopIteration:
        return lhs

    d.addCallback(lambda rhs: function(lhs, rhs))
    d.addCallback(lambda lhs: async_reduce(function, iterable, lhs))
    return d
```

It's still recursive instead of iterative, of course.

And a reducing function for computing the hexdigest is like:

```
def update_hash(hasher, s):
    hasher.update(s)
    return hasher
```

And so `calculate_checksum` becomes:

```
def calculate_checksum(open_file, chunk_size):
    chunks = read_those_chunks(open_file, chunk_size)
    d = async_reduce(update_hash, hashlib.sha256(), "")
    d.addErrback(lambda err: err.trap(EOFError))
    d.addCallback(lambda hasher: hasher.hexdigest())
    return d
```

which is a bit nicer for not having the `hasher` closure.

Of course, there are also many other ways you could rewrite this function to avoid `inlineCallbacks`.  The way I've chosen doesn't eliminate the use of a generator function so if that's what you wanted to escape it hasn't really helped.  If so, perhaps you can decompose the problem as I have done here into different pieces, none of which involve a generator.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I wanted to achieve. Could you please explain a bit more, why there must be a recursive call of `async_map` or `async_reduce` in `d.addCallback(lambda ignored: async_map(function, iterable))`?

Comment: Sure thing!  Edited some more text into the answer discussing recursion.