# FileTransferClient upload file performance

Tags: python, twisted

I'm having a performance issue with my SFTP Client. Uploading large file (aprox. 700MB) take forever and exits with failure (defer timeout occurs). While uploading `25MB` file finishes within a second.

This is function which implements `ISFTPFile`:

```
def _create_target_from_source(target, source):
    def _read_chunks_from_file(filename, chunk_size=1024 * 64):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
            chunk = fp.read(chunk_size)

            while chunk:
                yield chunk
                chunk = fp.read(chunk_size)

    offset = 0
    for chunk in _read_chunks_from_file(source):
        d = target.writeChunk(offset, chunk)
        offset += len(chunk)

    return d
```

And its call:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def _upload(client):

    mode_write = FXF_WRITE | FXF_CREAT | FXF_TRUNC
    client_file = client.openFile(target, mode_write, {})

    yield client_file.addCallback(_create_target_from_source, source)
    defer.returnValue(client)
```

I found some ideas with `Consumer/Producer` but I don't know how to use them with my example or if they even works with `FileTransferClient`. Is there any way to speedup upload of my client? Maybe my approach is wrong from beginning?

And second question. Is there a way to start uploading before the `client.openFile` fires with defered?

**UPDATE:**

To be honest I'm not sure if my code is slow or my approach is wrong since changing my code to look like this:

```
def _create_target_from_source(target, source):

    offsets_and_chunks = _read_chunks_with_offset_from_file(source)
    d = _async_map(target.writeChunk, offsets_and_chunks)

    return d

def _read_chunks_with_offset_from_file(filename, chunk_size):

    with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
        chunk = fp.read(chunk_size)

        offset = 0
        while chunk:
            yield offset, chunk
            chunk = fp.read(chunk_size)
            offset += chunk_size

def _async_map(writeChunk, payload):

    try:
        offset, chunk = next(payload)

    except StopIteration:
        return defer.succeed(True)

    d = writeChunk(offset, chunk)  # this is sloooooooooooow
    d.addCallback(lambda _: _async_map(writeChunk, payload))

    return d
```

Doesn't solve my performance issue. For example when I tested `paramiko.SFTPClient` uploading a 700MB file took 33seconds.

I think I'm doing something wrong with uploading file over SFTP in twisted but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: `_async_map` handles `StopIteration` with `pass` and then goes on to try to `writeChunk(offset, chunk)` where neither `offset` nor `chunk` is bound due to the exception. That will only matter at the very end but perhaps that's where your code is getting stuck. If fixing this doesn't help, I suggest instrumenting the code so you can see what it is spending its time. How many chunks does it write before it fails or you get bored?  How long does each write take to succeed? How much time is spent  between finishing one write and starting the next? More information will help guide your next steps.

Comment: Sorry, I did in fact change that `try/except` block returns `defer.succeed(True)` to handle `StopIteration`. Fixed with edit. Performance hasn't changed tho. I will try to profile my code and post results. BTW is there any other approach in twisted to send files to remote server over SSH? Or this is where my hope ends?

Comment: You could launch `scp`. :)  I think you've found the highest-level SFTP API currently offered by Twisted.  If you figure out how to get things working well, you might have something worth contributing to make it easier in the future (and to have less code to maintain yourself).  As far as profiling goes, I'd start with some simple log messages carefully emitted from the right places.  Profiling with cprofile/etc can be useful but it can be very difficult to make sense of a profile of a Twisted-based app, unfortunately.  Log/print is generally a lot easier and often tells you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this code is slow (and failure prone) is that it reads the entire file into memory and queues up all of the chunks to be written to the remote file.

Here's where that happens:

```
for chunk in _read_chunks_from_file(source):
    d = target.writeChunk(offset, chunk)
    offset += len(chunk)
```

The loop runs all the way through - synchronously.  One change you could make is to wait for each `writeChunk` to succeed before continuing on to the next.

There are a number of ways to convert the synchronous loop into an asynchronous one.  You could use `inlineCallbacks` and yield `d` on each iteration.  Or you could use my answer from [How refactor readChunk from SFTPFile to stop using inlineCallbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006466/how-refactor-readchunk-from-sftpfile-to-stop-using-inlinecallbacks) to do something similar without `inlineCallbacks`.